# How to serialize and deserialize list of object arrays with flexjson?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, flexjson

does anybody know how to serialize and deserialize a list of object arrays with flexjson?

What I have tried is this:

```
@GET 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getAllGeoData")
public String getAllGeoData(){
    List<Object[]>l = geoMapService.getAllGeoData();

    return new JSONSerializer().serialize(l);
}
```

Okay .. this works and when I call this webservice I get the following result:

[[50.0830292,8.2387331],[50.0830292,8.2387331],[50.0752003,8.2397125]]

In my Android Client I try to deserialize that List of Objects:

```
List<Object[]> l=new  JSONDeserializer<List<Object[]>>().deserialize(jsonstring);
```

and I get the following execption:

```
02-23 09:45:30.911: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 157 (Ljava/beans/IntrospectionException;)
02-23 09:45:30.921: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 157 (Ljava/beans/IntrospectionException;)
02-23 09:45:30.921: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x16a
02-23 09:45:30.921: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY:  rejected Lflexjson/ObjectBinder;.bindIntoObject (Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object;
02-23 09:45:30.921: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x016a
02-23 09:45:30.931: WARN/dalvikvm(270): VFY:  rejected Lflexjson/ObjectBinder;.bindIntoObject (Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object;
02-23 09:45:30.931: WARN/dalvikvm(270): Verifier rejected class Lflexjson/ObjectBinder;
02-23 09:45:30.941: WARN/dalvikvm(270): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-23 09:45:30.941: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
02-23 09:45:30.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270): java.lang.VerifyError: flexjson.ObjectBinder
02-23 09:45:30.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270):     at flexjson.JSONDeserializer.createObjectBinder(JSONDeserializer.java:169)
02-23 09:45:30.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270):     at flexjson.JSONDeserializer.deserialize(JSONDeserializer.java:149)
02-23 09:45:30.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270):     at com.mobilesociato.services.RemoteServiceGeoData$GeoDataThread.run(RemoteServiceGeoData.java:76)
02-23 09:45:30.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(270):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Help would be appreciated

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of the flexjson package you supplied is not compatible with your android version. Did you add this to the libs/ directory of the app?

Flexjson 2.1 is supposed to work on Android according [to this](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) (scroll to the bottom).

As `org.json` package is "built in" into Android, would it be a viable way to just use that package instead?

Comment: Yes, I´ve added the flexjson.jar to the libs/ directory of my app. I´ve tried to work with the org.json package. But when I try to deserialize the data, I get an exception that the json string has to start with "{"

Comment: and I don´t know what to do now ... the org.json does not work .. flexjson does not work. Is there maybe something wrong with the serialization. Do you know any other lib except flexjson the makes serialization easy?

Comment: FJ 2.1 is supposed to work according to the home page. Do you perhaps use an old/special version that produces the '[‘ - or some global setting? the ‘[' does not seem to be valid Json (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON )

Comment: No, I use the latest version 2.1. and yes '[' is not valid. the first character has to be '{'. but serializeing simple objects works fine. might there problems serializing lists? is it possible to serialize a list of objects arrays? do I maybe have to use these transformers? however they work ..

Comment: I think the basic issue is not the android side, but the server side. You say `String get...()` but the return value is a flattened list. I think you should do `List get...()`  to get the server side magic to serialize the result into the correct JSON which can then easily be parsed.

Comment: I did already. Instead of using flexjson, I use gson. It creates json valid data. But know I have problems deserialize the data on the android side. are there maybe problems in generall using libs like flexjson and gson in an android app?

Comment: Okay .. I solved the problem. I got the exception during deserialization because I used android 1.6. with android 2.1 it works